# JMeter | Groovy | Add Column to Aggregate.csv file after test completion

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want to add two extra columns to the aggregate.csv file generated after the JMeter test. I want the code should be written by using JSR223 PostProcesser and groovy as language.

**CSV file generated after test got finish**
[image: CSV file generated after test]

**CSV file after adding two other columns**
[image: asasasa]

Need Help with this requirement

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you **really** want:

```
def newFile = new File('aggregate-with-2-new-columns.csv')

new File('aggregate.csv').readLines().eachWithIndex { line, index ->
    if (index == 0) {
        newFile << line << ',' << 'Application Name' << ',' << 'Agent name' << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    } else {
        newFile << line << ',' << 'App1' << ',' << 'Run1' << System.getProperty('line.separator')
    }
}
```

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates) article for some potentially useful code snippets

However be informed about [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder), according to it JSR223 PostProcessors are being executed after [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) so I think that your CSV file won't exist at this moment yet.

Wouldn't it be better to consider using [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property instead?

Comment: Hi Dmitri
Thanks for this info I will try that, But before that, as you pointed out about Sample Variable. I want to mention my initial requirement-->
I want a CSV file having two extra columns mentioned in the question after the test.
The value of the extra column may be we can pass from properties or user-defined variable.
Currently we are using jmeter plugin to convert JMeter JTL to CSV
Let me know if you have any alternative for that